# Django - Null Integrity error not allowing POST

Tags: python, django

The error that I am getting when trying to POST is:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "interest_category_id" of relation "teamStart_project" violates not-null constraint
```

Here are my Serializers:

```
class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Interests
        fields = ('id', 'interest_name')


class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'project_title',
            'project_description',
            'interest_category',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        )
```

Here are my models:

```
class Interests(models.Model):
    interest_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.interest_name


class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project_description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    interest_category = models.ForeignKey(Interests, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Project name:" + "\n" + self.project_title + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "Created By:" + "\n" + self.created_by.username
```

I can get rid of the error by removing  `interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()` but this issue is, if I do not remove this line, the frontend shows the ID of `interest_category` and not the respective name. For example, this is what the frontend will show:

```
With this line: interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Project Title: TestItem1
Project Description: TestItem1Desc
Interest Category: Django
```

```
Without the line:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Project Title: TestItem1
Project Description: TestItem1Desc
Interest Category: 1
```

When I have the `interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()`, I am able to get the correct String Related name that I need to be displayed but I get the NullIntegrity error stating that the column of `"interest_category_id"` violates the not-null constraint.

Whereas, If I do not have that line I can POST with no issues or errors but I cannot display the correct String Related name, it will only show the ID of `interest_category`

**How can I get the name of the item, in order to display the item without having to worry about the NullIntegrity error with the `interest_category = serializers.StringRelatedField()` line.**

Answer (score 0):

change that `interest_category_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()` to
`interest_category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`

and add the following function to your `ProjectsSerializer`

```
def get_interest_category_name(self, instance):
    return instance.interest_category.interest_name
```

and then add `"interest_category_name"` in your `fields` of `ProjectsSerializer`. That will solve your problem.